# render kendo template inside an html table

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is it possible in any way to render the table rows of a table with a kendo template?

Here's how it should look **but it won't render the rows inside the table** since a `<table>` doesn't allow a `<span>` or `<script>` tag inside it

```
 <table class="table-striped">
     <span data-template="myTable" data-bind="source: numbers"></span>
     <script id="myTable" type="text/x-kendo-template">
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <span data-bind="text:number"></span>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </script>
 </table>


 <script>
     var numbers = [{number:1},{number:2},{number:3}]
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by putting the `<script>` tag for the template outside the table and binding from the `<table>` by adding a `<tbody>` tag inside the table like this:

```
<table class="table-striped">
    <tbody data-template="myTable" data-bind="source: numbers"></tbody>
</table>

<script id="myTable" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text:number"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
   <table id="output" class="table table-striped"></table>


  var tablerows = '';
  var template = kendo.template("<tr><td><span>#: number #</span></td></tr>");
  var numbers = [{number:1},{number:2},{number:3}];
  for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    tablerows += template(numbers[i]);
  }
  $("#output").empty().append(tablerows);
```

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UYuno)**

You could also put the loop inside the template...

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works great! However, I wanted to use MVVM instead of just js. See my answer